# What is the difference between java.lang.String vs String (Java)

Tags: java, logging, mybatis

I'm fairly new to java but have been studying it for quite a bit. I am currently learning Spring Boot with MyBatis and am getting this frustrating compilation error. I am trying to implement this Hash Service and during this process, I am trying to catch and log any errors. The problem is when I try and use the logger that I import from mybatis to log the error I get the compilation error
`required type java.lang.String`
`Provided: String`
I was previously under the impression that these two classes were the same but I'm guessing the String class isn't the same as the java.lang.String class? Or is there something else going on? Here is the actual code for you to look at. Could someone help me?

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.mybatis.logging.Logger;
import org.mybatis.logging.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.Base64StringKeyGenerator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.lang.String;

@Component
public class HashedService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HashedService.class);

    public String getHashedValue(String data, String salt) {
        byte[] hashedValue = null;

        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(data.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 5000, 128);
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            hashedValue = factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            java.lang.String error = e.getMessage();
            logger.error(error);
        }

        return Base64.encodeBase64String(hashedValue);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I am using intellij

Comment: Have you defined a class called String yourself?

Comment: No, but I thought String was automatically set to java.lang.String. No?

Comment: I traced the e.getMessage() method all the way to the Throwables class and that method returns a java.lang.String class object. So I'm not really sure what compilation error is alluding to...

Comment: In `Java`, `String` is not *set* to `java.lang.String`.  But `String` is a class in the `java.lang` package.  And that package is implicitly imported to make anything in that package available for use.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```gradle
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
}
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis-spring
compile group: 'org.mybatis', name: 'mybatis-spring', version: '2.0.5'
```

And I found that method `error` from `org.mybatis.logging.Logger` looks like this:

```java
public void error(Supplier<String> s) {
  log.error(s.get());
}
```

I think you shouldn't use the logger from MyBatis.

You can try to replace:

```java
import org.mybatis.logging.Logger;
import org.mybatis.logging.LoggerFactory;
```

with:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```